# mysqli->affected_rows no funciona con procedimiento almacenado

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo un trozo de código que inserta un registro en la tabla `persona (id_persona, apellidos, nombres)`, estoy utilizando MySQLi y PHP5 y tengo lo siguiente:

```
$query="CALL persona('".$nombres."','".$apellidos."')";
$mysqli->query($query);
$filas = $mysqli->affected_rows;   //Aquí siempre me muestra 1, se inserte o no el registro
$id_insertado = $mysqli->insert_id //Siempre me muestra 0
```

pd. si se inserta el registro con ese procedimiento almacenado.

Pero si cambio por ejemplo a esto:

```
$query="INSERT INTO persona(nombres,apellidos)values('".$nombres."','".$apellidos."')";
$mysqli->query($query);
$filas = $mysqli->affected_rows;    //Funciona bien, devuelve el número de registros insertados
$id_insertado = $mysqli->insert_id; //Me muestra el id insertado
```

Mi procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE persona(
        IN pnombres TEXT,
        IN papellidos TEXT,
    )
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
  persona
(
  nombres,
  apellidos
VALUE (
  pnombres,
  papellidos);

END;
```

Desearía por favor me apoyen con esta duda, ¿estoy haciendo algo incorrecto, o hay que agregar algo en el procedimiento almacenado, o hay alguna otra forma para poder saber que realmente se insertó el registro? Ya sea en MySQL o PHP, aparte de consultar el último ID, con funciones propias de MySQL.

Comment: Estaba editando la pregunta pero me he encontrado con un problema: el código del procedimiento almacenado es incorrecto. Le falta un paréntesis de cierre y una de las palabras clave está mal escrita (`VALUE` en lugar de `VALUES`). No sé si eso es un fallo al escribir la pregunta (y debiera editarlo), o si es el motivo por el que no funciona la inserción con el procedimiento (y corregirlo hará que se resuelva la pregunta). Por favor, copia el código del procedimiento almacenado tal cual lo tienes.

Comment: EL CODIGO SQL CONTIENE ERRORES: INSERT INTO persona ( nombres, apellidos **)** **--falta el cierre de parentesis** VALUE**S** (--ES VALUES NO VALUE pnombres, papellidos ); un ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo: [Insert en store procedure](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_INSERT.php)
SALUDOS.

Comment: He completado la edición de la pregunta después de confirmar que incluso después de corregir los fallos en el código del procedimiento, el error seguía ocurriendo. La causa real del fallo es que estás haciendo el `SELECT` dentro de un procedimiento almacenado y parece que a MySQL eso no le termina de gustar

Answer (score 3):

Como indica ratlab en otra respuesta, el código del procedimiento almacenado es incorrecto, pero haciendo pruebas comprobé que incluso con el código corregido, el registro se insertaba pero `mysqli->insert_id` devolvía 0 en lugar del último id. El problema no es el código del procedimiento almacenado en sí, sino cómo funciona MySQL cuando inserta desde un procedimiento.

Como se especifica en [esta respuesta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12761193/3695983) (en inglés) y que puedes encontrar en los [archivos de Google Code](http://dash-docsets.googlecode.com/git-history/22e185beb66f01566cb9d7aac77bb44fc01aeacc/Docsets/PHP.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/res/mysqli.insert-id.html) (ya no está disponible en el enlace dado en esa respuesta), el error que describes ocurre porque el `INSERT` ocurre dentro de un procedimiento almacenado.

Dejo aquí una traducción aproximada del texto original:

> Notar que si se llama a un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL para insertar un nuevo registro y luego se hace `$db->insert_id;` obtendrás un valor de 0 y no el último ID que se insertó.
>
> Es por tanto necesario añadir una línea al procedimiento almacenado tal como
>
> ```
> select last_insert_id() as intRecordKey;
> ```
>
> después del INSERT para que la consulta devuelva el nuevo valor.

---

Para solucionar este problema tendrías dos opciones:

**A) Seleccionar y devolver el último ID insertado en el procedimiento almacenado**

Como se sugiere en el comentario, la idea sería devolver el resultado de un SELECT del último ID insertado, que se puede obtener directamente en la función `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Así, el procedimiento almacenado cambiaría ligeramente:

```sql
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE persona (
        IN pnombres TEXT,
        IN papellidos TEXT
   )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO persona (nombres, apellidos) VALUES (pnombres, papellidos);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS ultimoid;
END

;;
```

Y el PHP también necesitaría una pequeña modificación:

```
$query = "CALL persona('".$nombres."','".$apellidos."')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
$filas = $mysqli->affected_rows;
$id_insertado = $resultado->fetch_assoc()["ultimoid"];
```

---

**B) Devolver el último ID como un parámetro de salida del procedimiento almacenado**

Personalmente iría con la opción A, pero como una alternativa también podrías cambiar el procedimiento almacenado para que tuviera un parámetro de salida (p.e.: `OUT ultimo_id INT`), inicializarlo usando `SET` y la función +y luego leer el valor de dicho parámetro en una nueva `query()`.

En este caso el procedimiento almacenado cambiaría a:

```sql
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE persona (
        IN pnombres TEXT,
        IN papellidos TEXT,
        OUT ultimoid INT
   )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO persona (nombres, apellidos) VALUES (pnombres, papellidos);
    SET ultimoid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END

;;
```

Y el PHP cambiaría a:

```
$query = "CALL persona('".$nombres."','".$apellidos."', @ultimoid)";
$mysqli->query($query);
$filas = $mysqli->affected_rows;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT @ultimoid");
$id_insertado = $result->fetch_assoc()["ultimoid"];
```